# ¿En qué orden se ejecutan varios activadores en google sheets que responden al mismo evento?

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

En una hoja de cálculo de google tengo un sript con un activador que responde al envío de un formulario. A su vez tengo instalada una extensión, Autocrat, que responde también al envío de un formulario...

1 ¿Hay alguna manera de determinar el orden en que se ejecuten?
2 ¿Hay alguna manera de saber en qué orden se van a ejecutar?

El asunto es que me gustaría que primero se ejecutase mi script y después Autocrat, pero no sé como controlarlo.

Gracias

Comment: Hola Juan, en teoría debería ser posible llamar desde tu script a una extensión de chrome o intentar controlar desde la extensión algún "trigger" o desencadenador o ejecución de script adicional después de alguna operación sobre la extensión [Using the google apps script exection api in Chrome Extensions](https://hawksey.info/blog/2017/05/using-the-google-apps-script-execution-api-in-chrome-extensions/#gref). Es decir, en lugar de controlar el orden de 2 cosas independientes, quizás quitar el activador de ambos y controlarlo manualmente desde 1 punto. Espero que te ayude, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Minerill0  y gracias por responder. Quizá no me expliqué bien o no entendí bien tu respuesta, per el caso es que la extensión está instalada en la hoja de cálculo, no en Chrome.

Comment: Ahh, disculpa, fuí yo que asocié "extensión" con navegador, en lugar de la hoja de cálculo. En tal caso, creo que estamos hablando directamente del código,  y capacidades de Google Sheet scripting para manejar los eventos sobre una extensión. Investigando he descubierto [CreateResponseItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#createResponse(String)), que te permite agregar un item al final del formulario con el que controlar eventos, quizás por ahí puedas hacer algo.